# Using CoffeeScript with cypress.io

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, e2e-testing, cypress

I have a problem when using [cypress.io](https://www.cypress.io/) with CoffeeScript. The tests fail with the following exception:

```
describe('testFn', function() {
                ^
ParseError: reserved word "function"
```

Code:

```
describe 'testFn', () ->
    it 'testIt', () ->
        # a test
```

CoffeeScript is supported by cypress.io as show in [the documentation](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/writing-and-organizing-tests.html#Support-Files)

I have the cypress.io dependency installed and I have tried using it with the [@cypress/coffee-script package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@cypress/coffee-script) but it does not seem to work.

package.json:

```
...
"cypress": "^1.0.3",
"@cypress/coffee-script": "^0.1.2",
...
```

The tests do run when using .js files that have the transpiled CoffeeScript code:

```
describe('testFn', function() {
  return it('testIt', function() {
    expect(true).to.equal(true);
  });
});
```

What could be the issue here?

Answer (score 1):

Cypress tests definitely work in CoffeeScript. As a developer at Cypress, I know because we write almost all of our own Cypress tests in CoffeeScript.

That being said, if you are using CoffeeScript 2, this is not supported (but is [coming soon](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/663)).

You shouldn't need to include our internal `@cypress/coffee-script` package. We only have this as a dependency for our own project, so that each piece of our application can share the same CoffeeScript version.

My suggestions at the moment:

1. Double check that the file extension of your test file is `.coffee`
2. If you have a lot of test code, simplify it. Remove 1 line at a time until it works.

The test code below should work if you copy/paste it:

```
describe 'testFn', () ->
  it 'testIt', () ->
    expect(true).to.equal(true)
```